# Changing status buffer in emacs 24 to show file path

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I use emacs in terminal, hence title bar is not available, How do I see full file path or at least last 2 directories of file.

[image]

Comment: You need to configure mode-line-format. See [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2338), it's not exactly what you need, but similar.

Comment: Tangentially, maybe you are actually looking for [`uniquify`](https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html) although it doesn't support precisely the behavior you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/how-can-i-display-the-parent-directory-of-the-current-file-in-the-modeline post

Basically I added this

```
(setq-default mode-line-buffer-identification
              (let ((orig  (car mode-line-buffer-identification)))
                `(:eval (cons (concat ,orig (abbreviate-file-name default-directory))
                              (cdr mode-line-buffer-identification)))))
```